# Angular - Owl Slider doesn't work properly when I load data

Tags: angular, slider, components, gallery, owl-carousel

When I put static data for the gallery, everything works fine. Here's the code:

TS:

```
export class ObservacoesComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

mySlideTexts = ["DATA1", "DATA2", "DATA3", "DATA4", "DATA5"];
mySlideOptionsText = { items: 3, dots: false, nav: false };

ngOnInit() {}

}
```

HTML:

```
<owl-carousel [options]="mySlideOptionsText" [items]="texts" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding']">
    <div class="item mx-2" *ngFor="let text of mySlideTexts;let i = index">
        <p style="padding:10px; margin: 5px;">{{text}}</p>
        <p>18/06/2018</p>
    </div>
</owl-carousel>
```

[image]

But then, when I try to load real data, this is what happens:

[image]

The gallery is not longer a gallery. The items follow now a vertical orientation and there is no scroll like before. Here's the new .ts code:

```
export class ObservacoesComponent implements OnInit {

    token : any;
    woundId : any;
    wound : Wound;
    interventions : Array<Intervention>;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private chartsReportService : ChartsReportService ) {  

        this.woundId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('woundId');       
        this.token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token');

    }

    mySlideTexts = [];
    mySlideOptionsTextTratamentos = {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.woundId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('woundId');       
        this.token =this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token');
        this.getWoundById() 
    }

    getWoundById() {    
    this.chartsReportService.getWoundById(this.woundId, this.token).subscribe((v) => {
    this.wound = v.result;
    this.interventions = v.result.intervention;

    //ver como fica esta informação
    for(let interv of this.interventions)
    {
        this.mySlideTexts.push(interv.observations);
    }
    });

  }
}
```

Do you know where the problem might be? Thanks.

Comment: Hello you get any solution for this?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Hi. I don't remember if this is correct, but I think it was because I was putting the wrong links or wrong versions of owl sliderin that project. Check if your links are correct.